# A Question of Ordinal - İnitial Segment

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

- Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. Let $z$ be an initial segment of $\alpha$. Then either $z=\alpha$ or $z\in\alpha$. Thus, an initial segment of an ordinal is an ordinal.

Proof. If $z\neq\alpha$, then $\alpha\setminus z$ does have a minimal element, say $x$. Then

$$z=\left\{y\in\alpha : y<\alpha\right\}=\left\{y\in\alpha : y\in\alpha\right\}=x\in\alpha.$$

**I have a question in the proof:** How did writer connect from  $\left\{y\in\alpha : y<\alpha\right\}$ to the set $\left\{y\in\alpha : y\in\alpha\right\}=x\in\alpha.$ Can you explain?

Comment: I think that the chain of equalities contains two typos: it should be $z=\{y\in\alpha:y<\color{red}{x}\}$ and similarly the second one. After you fix them, you should easily see why the conclusion holds.

Comment: @Leo163 İ think so there is a typo